# windows server 2012 DNS issue

Tags: dns, windows-server-2012-r2

- I have an internal domain "smartxxxx.jo" in my company connected to the internet ...
- and we have an external domain for email server and website with the same name.
- on domain PCs the primary DNS address is the internal DNS Server IP "192.168.5.100" ... i cannot change it because sharing'll has issues !

when i want to access mail.smartxxxx.jo or smartxxxx.jo , it won't open and a message appears and say the website is not found, but when i try to access mail.smartxxxx.jo or smartxxxx.jo and the DNS server is disconnected ... it success ! ....

so , i think when I request smartxxxx.jo and the domain is connected to network , the local DNS is replay .... how to make DNS server direct the web address to the internet instead of searching locally

**this issue appears even when i place www or the external website IP Address**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved .... my issue wasn't because of split zone DNS >>>> the only thing i had to do was add a secondary dns server

http://gopalthorve.com/configure-secondary-dns-server-in-windows-server-2008/